# I create a button by script. Can I call other function by clicking the button? I do it like this, but fail

Tags: javascript

I add a button in this script. Can I use the button to call other function. like this: newinput.onclick = "check();"; I try it but no response.

```
  inform = document.getElementById('addinput');

  newinput = document.createElement('input');
  newinput.type = "text";
  newinput.name = "NumA" + i;
  newinput.id = "NumA" + i;
  newinput.value = a;
  inform.appendChild(newinput);


  newinput = document.createElement('input');
  newinput.type = "button";
  newinput.name = "submit";
  newinput.value = "Check";

  **newinput.onclick = "check();";**

  inform.appendChild(newinput);

  }


  function check() {
  window.alert("It is test!");
  }
```

Comment: `check()` will execute the check function and assign the result of the execution to `onClick`, remove the `()` to assign the function to `onClick` instead without execution. i.e: `newinput.onclick = check;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
newinput.setAttribute('onClick','yourFunction();');
```

although you may need to forego the semicolon, I am not 100% sure.

```
newinput.setAttribute('onClick','yourFunction()');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the function name without parenthesis:

```
newinput.onclick = check;
```

See how it works [on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akT8t/).

Explenation:
By putting the function name in paranthesis you invoke the function in that exact spot. The `onclick` would actually be assigned the return value of that function. On the other hand, passing just the name of the object (function in this case), you assiging the reference to that object (function).